# Django>=3.2 and dbshell

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-3.2

Did something change with Django>=3.2 with respect to MySQL. I have not changed my database credentials.

### Credentials work

Trying to connect with the old credentials via

```
mysql --user=user -p
```

and the original password works.

### Django admin commands work...

```sh
python manage.py runserver
```

and

```sh
python manage.py shell_plus
```

works.

### ...except for `dbshell`

```sh
python manage.py dbshell
```

returns

```sh
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
CommandError: "mysql --user=user --host=localhost --default-character-set=utf8mb4 my_project_db" returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

### Question...

What changed? Why does dbshell not work?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  (release notes 3.2: [Dropped support for MySQL 5.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/))

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.11, for osx10.9 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: What version of mysqlclient do you use?

Comment: "Django requires mysqlclient 1.4.0 or later." (source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/)

Comment: mysqlclient==2.0.3